# Ribono Shel Olam pronunciation

Tags: hebrew, pronunciation, aleph-bet-letters

I haven't studied Hebrew in 50 years and cannot read it anymore. I wonder if anyone has any suggestions on how I can get the pronunciation of Rabbi Nachman's phrase "Ribono Shel Olam" both in the way he would have pronounced it and the standard (biblical?) Hebrew pronunciation? I think the written Hebrew is ריבונו של עולם.

Comment: I think this may be a harder question than you realize. There is no "standard" Hebrew pronunciation and we frankly don't really know exactly how Hebrew was pronounced in biblical times. Also, just so you know, although based on some googling around it does seem that Rebbi Nachman did prescribe reciting the phrase as a sort of mantra, he did not coin the expression.

Comment: I find listening to old klezmer songs (e.g. 1905 and onwards) useful to see how people pronounced hebrew in Europe.

Comment: The term “Ribono Shel Olam” didn’t originate with Rabbi Nachman of Breslov...

Comment: Saba (R' Yisrael Odesser z"tzl) saying it sounds like "riBO[I]no shel O[I]lam" as can be heard on SuperSaba Track 4 https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11XlId7edPLdGjMiUFggkSGdbpJIn7hZa

Comment: Hebrew ought to be riboNO shel OLAM (though ribon is borrowed from Targum/Aramaic) so this is a hybrid phrase.  But practically if following R' Nachman z"l's advice he said to talk to God in language of your choice how-ever you're comfortable.

Comment: In Tiberian Hebrew the phrase would have probably been something like [ʀibboːˈnoː ˈʃεːl ʕoːˈlɔːm] in IPA.